# React OnClick Function not Binding

Tags: function, reactjs, bind

I have an `onClick` handler that is bound to `currentAreas` component. The `onClick` handler is called simultaneously when the `currentAreas` component is called, but does not work after that.

`onClick` does not work when I try to click the anchor tag and I think it might be due to the way I'm binding the `onClick` function.

currentAreas.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class currentAreas extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { onClick } = this.props;

    return(
        <div className="list-group panel">
          <a href="#demo3" className="list-group-item" onClick={onClick("All", "All")} >All</a>

        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

currentList.js (Main component)

```
class currentList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.updateLocation = this.updateLocation.bind(this);
    }

  updateLocation(name, nameLocation){
    console.log(name);
    console.log(nameLocation);
  }

    render() {
        return (
           <div className="step-3-container">

            <CurrentAreas 
              onClick ={this.updateLocation} />
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever your javascript interpreter "sees" a "()" it tries to execute the function that is before "()". Therefore, what your code is actually doing is **executing** `onClick` (the one that came from `props`), passing as arguments "All" and "All". So, what you need to do is, instead of calling it yourself, let the `onClick` handler call it.

In other words, the `onClick` prop must receive a `function`.

One possible solution is to wrap your `onClick` into an arrow function, doing something like that:

```
<a href="#demo3" onClick={() => onClick("All", "All")}>All</a>
```

Or, you may `bind` the parameters to your function (bind returns a function, so it will fit well on `onClick`).

```
<a href="#demo3" onClick={onClick.bind(null, "All", "All")}>All</a>
```

The first `bind` parameter is the `this` value inside the binded function.

FMI about `bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 2):

Youre executing the function during the declaration of the component, which likely means youre triggering it on render, not click

```
onClick={onClick("All", "All")}
```

needs to be

```
onClick={onClick.bind(null, "All", "All")}
```

or

```
onClick={function(){ onClick("All", "All"); }}
```

The `onClick` of a react component needs a callback that can be executed. you are passing in the return value of `this.props.onClick` because youre calling it right away with arguments